# Multiple ways of connecting to a network drive on the same host

Tags: windows, powershell, network-drive

Both `net use` and `new-psdrive` seem to be unable to map two drives from the same host normally.
You can cheat your way into getting TWO drives by using the IP and the name of the host, but as far as i know there it stops.

But annoyingly, i am in the situation where i need three locations mapped.
We have a file server that contains the profile directory of users and a shared network directory for the company to save various things.

I need to administrate both of these, PLUS, obviously, my OWN profile directory, so i need to map `\\server01\users` , `\\server01\FlyingThunder` AND `\\server01\CompanyStuff`.

What can i do here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `New-PSdrive` to have multiple connections to same server with one user account(but parameter `-credential` must used only for first drive other will use same credential). But if you want use different user accounts for each share, you need to add aliases into DNS and configure Samba with the same netbios aliases. With that trick, Windows happily makes multiple connections with different user name/password logons. Basically, it doesn't realize that it is connecting to the same machine.

Comment: `

You can use New-PSdrive to have multiple connections to same server with one user account(but parameter -credential must used only for first drive other will use same credential)` what do you mean? if i use new-psdrive to map multiple directories it doesnt work - possibly because one directory is a subdirectory of the other like i said?